# Find constants $a, b, c$ such that function $f$ is continuous, derivative on $(−1,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Function $f: (-1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is define like
$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}[rcl]%
ae^\frac{-1}{x}+b; && x>0\\
c; && x=0\\
\frac{x^2}{\ln^2(1+x)}; && -1<x<0\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

a) Find constants $a, b, c$ such that function $f$ is continuous on $(-1, \infty)$.

b) Find constants $a, b, c$ such that function $f$ is derivative on $(-1, \infty)$.

So in example a) I got $b=c=1$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$
For example b) I calculate $$\lim_{h \nearrow 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \nearrow 0}\frac{\frac{h^2}{\ln^2(1+h)}-1}{h}=1$$
and $$\lim_{h \searrow 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h \searrow 0}\frac{ae^\frac{-1}{h}+1-1}{h}=0$$

So in b) left and right limit is not the same. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Please show your proofs. Why $b=c=1$ ? What is the limit of $x^2/\ln^2(1+x)$ in $0$

Comment: That limit is 1, and first limit $\lim_{x \to 0}ae^\frac{-1}{x}+b=b$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}c=c$ and that is why is $b=c=1$